# Javascript - Filter arrays in object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of objects with filtered values

```
// desired output

     [
         { "2017-02-01": "09:00" },
         { "2017-02-02": "09:00" },
     ]
```

My Js object

```js
let res = {
  "2018-02-01": [
    {
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
    }
  ],
  "2018-02-02": [
    {
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
      "reference": null
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
      "reference": null
    }
  ]
}

// My attempt 
output = _.keys(res).map( i => res[i].filter( t => t.available))

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain **in words** what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated the question :)

Comment: If you notice, I highlighted *in words*. What I meant was what is the logic to filter objects? I did understand that you are trying to get the first available timeslot but I had to read your entire code for it.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```js
let res = {
  "2018-02-01": [
    {
      time: "09:00",
      available: true
    },
    {
      time: "10:00",
      available: false
    }
  ],
  "2018-02-02": [
    {
      time: "09:00",
      available: true,
      reference: null
    },
    {
      time: "10:00",
      available: false,
      reference: null
    }
  ]
};
let output = Reflect.ownKeys(res).map(key => ({
  [key]: res[key].filter(obj => obj.available)[0].time
}));
console.log(output);
```

your logic is basically correct with a little error because you didn't take a good control of your `return value` in `map` function.

And that is what i did:

```
[key]: /*basically  your code*/[0].time
```

Comment: @Rajesh, First `Reflect` is pure JavaScript concept. Look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys

Comment: @Rajesh, Second, it is very straight forward, what explanation you need?

Comment: @Rajesh, then instead of commenting sarcastically, better you should show some maturity and simply comment **Your code also looks good, better to add some explanation** that's it.

Comment: Also thanks for the link. Learned something new. For readers, do check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys#Browser_compatibility) before using

Comment: @Rajesh, if it was so then why did you delete your the very first comment? Anyways, please don't feel offended. Everyday we learn something new not only technical but other stuff as well :)

Comment: The first comment was deleted because its purpose was to request you to add an explanation, and you did. Not what I expected but still something. Also you added reference to reflect, so both my queries were resolved and hence that comment was no longer useful. Another useful habit(*removing any non-constructive comment*) you will learn over the course of time. Let me know if you have any other queries. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, what you need is the first timeslot that is available.

For this, you can loop over keys of response. Post that you can use `array.find` or `_.find` and get first value that is available.

Now create an object with date value as key and value as object.time

```js
let res = {
  "2018-02-01": [{
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
    }
  ],
  "2018-02-02": [{
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
      "reference": null
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
      "reference": null
    }
  ]
}

// My attempt 
output = Object.keys(res).reduce(function(acc, key) {
  const obj = res[key].find(x => !!x.available);
  if (!!obj)
    acc.push({
      [key]: obj.time
    });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `res` object using `for in` loop.
Find the object which has `available` as `true` using `Array.find` method.
Store `key/value` in an object and `push` the object in an array.

```js
let res = {
  "2018-02-01": [
    {
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
    }
  ],
  "2018-02-02": [
    {
      "time": "09:00",
      "available": true,
      "reference": null
    },
    {
      "time": "10:00",
      "available": false,
      "reference": null
    }
  ]
}

var arr = [];

for (var date in res) {
  arr.push({
    [date]: res[date].find(r => r.available).time
  });
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do using native javascript then you can use this code -

```
var arr = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(res)) {
    var obj = {};

    for (const o of value) {

        if (o.available) { obj[key] = o.time; }
    } 

    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```